# Fixed sidebar with header. Havent found the solution yet

Tags: html, css

I did try some designing in Figma but I am stuck now figuring out how to do something. I want a fixed sidebar, with the header full width until it reaches the sidebar (or at least, the button etc should not go through my sidebar)

My design, with on the right the sidebar: https://i.gyazo.com/eaf28c70587ad014777f065c524c4a92.png

What I have right now, as you can see the div inside the header is full width but it should be full width until it reaches sidebar: https://i.gyazo.com/a222cdaf11031095a13bfa35e3f1395a.png

My css:

HEADER:

```css
import styled from "styled-components"

export const NavWrapper = styled.nav`
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 10;
  border: solid red 1px;
  color: #fdfdfd;
`
```

SIDEBAR:

```css
export const SidebarRight = styled.div`
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 80px 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
`
```

Or is it fine how I styled it and should I use a different method of having the button and everything perfect inside the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `fixed` takes the item out of the document flow. There are a few ways to accomplish what you're trying to do it.

If your sidebar is always going to be the same width, you can just use a calc on the header to say `width: calc(100% - *sidebar-width*);`, but then you're going to do with the same thing for your main content.

I'd suggest that you change your structure a little bit and put a flex wrapper around the whole app. Separate the sidebar from a content wrapper, and then do the header and main content inside of that wrapper.

Here is a codepen for reference:
https://codepen.io/davidleininger/pen/bc3fe65aee84c21efe631492eaba7e14

Comment: Many thanks! I'll try it this afternoon but based on your codepen I can tell this is what I want.

Comment: Actually, it helped me a bit but I ran into some problems with your solution. I guess it is not really possible what I want, or I should redesign the header. [link](https://claroagency.gatsbyjs.io/) is what I have right now. Now when I add a section underneath, the sidebar isn't fixed and leaves whitespace underneath. You should be able to see the whole full width page, scroll underneath the sidebar. So I guess I need to have it fixed, right?

Comment: I can set it to fixed, let the header be full width and set some kind of margin calc on the button on the right?

Comment: Yeah. So if you use fixed, you'd just want to wrap the rest of the content in a wrapper and add the content in there. This way the wrapper gets set next to the fixed sidebar the whole time. Setting a margin or defining a width with `calc()` would work for this. I can put together another example if needed.

Comment: In the first example that I gave you, you could just keep adding stuff in the `.content-wrapper` div. That way the sidebar would always stay. Make it 100% height and position absolute or sticky the contents.